# merging a sparse tag to a branch when migrating from cvs to git

Tags: git, migration, branch, cvs, git-merge

I'm in the process of migrating from cvs to git. (Scoff if you will, but only if your company has been around for 15 years.)

I have some old-timey CVS tags that *only tag some files in the repo,* not all of them. When I check out those tags, it looks like a repo in which everything untagged has been deleted. That's a well-known difference in the branching model between cvs/svn on the one hand and git on the other.

I'd like to make a new branch like this:

- start with my master branch and make a new release branch.
- replace only the files tagged with `tags/A`.
- then on top of that, replace only the files tagged with `tags/B`.
- then commit the whole lot.

Ideally, the new branch would contain the old history of the tagged files as well as the master branch.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: I have never had to do that in particular, but I'd start by seeing what `cvs2*` (starting with cvs2git) does with them.  If all else fails though, just do it by hand: convert most of the repository with cvs2git, then make some special case items, and use filter-branch and or graft/replace to wedge them in.  This is only practical if you have a small set of these, otherwise you may need to automate that too.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to do this after the fact, now in CVS, to prepare your cvs repo for the cvs2git script? Step through all tags and add the missing files to the tag. `cvs tag` on its own, without `-F` will not move a tag. So you can re-apply tag/A, based on tag/B and it will only apply it to files that are not already tagged, which is exactly what you want.

It might turn out that you simply have too many tags to make this practical. I'm thinking 20,000 tags x 5 min/tag = 34 days.

But I don't know if it would be much faster to do it in git. And once you're in git, you'd have to clean up all the cvs2git artifacts: fixup commits etc associated with each tag. But I could imagine, in theory, stepping through each tag, checking out more files, adding them in, amending the commit (with author and date preserved through the appropriate GIT_ environment variables), moving the tag, comparing it to the previous commit that's actually on the branch in case you can just move the tag back one.

Also, is it important to you that your tags be on the named branch that they're supposed to be on? Because with all those fixup commits they will not be, even with your fixups. It might be pragmatic to ensure your `master` branch gets converted in the most elegant and meaningful way while letting some of the older branches be a bit crusty.

**Update**

Just a crazy thought. Would it make some sense to do cvs2svn, fix up the tags, then svn2git? I know it sounds kinda crazy, but subversion has the changesets of git, but the ability to work on a file-by-file basis like cvs so it could be the best place to fix up the tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b release master
git merge --no-commit -s ours tags/A tags/B
git checkout tags/A -- .
git checkout tags/B -- .

git commit  # put the above sequence in the commit message if you have love in your heart
```

The first command is "checkout the current master but as the new branch named release:".

The second is "set up but do not commit a no-op merge from tags/A and tags/B".  Before committing, you can arrange any merge result you want.

… in particular, the third and fourth commands load the versions of what's in those two commits.

Comment: Perhaps if he wants to fix up `tags/A`, then the git checkout in the recipe can be `git checkout -b fixA tags/A~`. The new commit will be created  on top of the same parent as `tags/A`. Then `tags/A` can be moved to `fixA` (or even `fixA~` if it turns out that they're identical). (And again, for the commit you will want to set the various GIT_AUTHOR etc. environment variables to give it the same author/committer/dates as tags/A originally did.)